# Why last two print statements do not print anything after typecasting pointer 'ptr'?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wanted to see what happens after typecasting an integer pointer `ptr` to character pointer `ptr0`. But, last two print statements do not print any output to the console.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int var  = 1025;
    int *ptr = &var;

    //~ addr of var
    cout << ptr << endl;

    //~ value of var - dereferencing 
    cout << *ptr << endl;

    char *ptr0;

    //~ typecasting int to char
    ptr0 = (char*)ptr; // also tried: ptr0 = (char*)&var

    cout << ptr0 << endl;
    cout << *ptr0 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output shows:**

```
0x7ffd6d8f4b94
1025
```

**expected result:**

```
0x7ffd6d8f4b94
1025

0x7ffd6d8f4b94
1
```

Comment: Also, the `char*` version is probably printing nothing because the first byte(s) of the `int` are probably 0 (hard to tell without knowing where you ran this).

Comment: @vandench they expect "1" because it's the first digit of the number, as they seem to wrongly think that casting to `char*` will actually convert a number to a string representing that number.

Comment: @vandench sorry, I made a mistake. I edited my codes expected result

Comment: @zipperblock if my supposition is correct (about converting) look for the `itoa` function.

Comment: Character code 0x01 is Start if Heading, the character code for the character 1 is 0x31.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't think so. 1025 == 0x401, so the last byte is indeed a 1 which is why it is reasonable to expect that to be printed. (And indeed it is printed if you cast it back to int)

Comment: @vandench I was responding to "why do you think it should be 1"

Comment: @vandench well, you deleted your comment, so I can't re-read it, but at the time I thought that was what you meant.

Comment: @Evg I tried what you suggested. It is giving me output 1. But cout << ptr0 << endl; still does not give proper out.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am running this code using geany

Comment: @zipperblock printing a char* interprets it as a string, which is still comprised of an ascii control code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both lines do print something. However, this "something" is unprintable.

In C++ `char*` is considered to be a string. So, unlike every other pointer type, `cout` will not tell you the address that a `char*` stores, but it will interpret the the memory that it is pointing to as a null-terminated array of `char`s. Again, this is because `char*` gets a special treatment in C++. In your case, the memory where your `1025` (or `0x00000401` in hexadecimal) is stored looks like this:

```
01 04 00 00
```

If you let `ptr0` point to this, it will point to the `01`. As it is a `char*` it will be interpreted as a string of length two: The first character is `01`, the second one is `04` and then there is a `00` which determines the end. Looking at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) we see that those characters refer to some unprintable characters (I have zero to little idea what they are (have been) good for). So, `cout` doesn't print anything but the following `endl`.

`cout << *ptr0 << endl;` on the other hand will only print the first character of that string, which again cannot be printed.

If you want to print the address and the number instead of the string and character, you will have to cast them back to some other pointer and some integer, respectively, e.g. like this:

```
cout << (void*)ptr0 << endl;
cout << (int)*ptr0 << endl;
```

See [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bZgq6LrZDVJ8qdfP) how it prints your expected result.

Comment: Which is in contradiction whith what you told me in the comments but was more or less what I was trying to convey (wrongly assuming the layout would have been `00 00 04 01` admittedly) :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca right, in the other comment a wrongly used "last" for describing the position of `01` while I should have said `first`. And of course it depends on the endianness :)

Comment: in the old days.. 0x01 and 0x04 were used in serial communication SOH start of header and EOT end of transmission where used in different protocols.